# How to add multiple path on same port VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost, phpmyadmin

I want to add multiple paths like "localhost:8080/phpmyadmin" and "localhost:8080/index.php" but it doesn't want to work I create a phpmyadmin.conf in conf-availables with

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration
<VirtualHost *:8080>
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        <IfModule mod_mime.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        </IfModule>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        </FilesMatch>

        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/
        php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php.c>
        <IfModule mod_mime.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        </IfModule>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        </FilesMatch>

        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/
        php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
            AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
        </IfModule>
        Require valid-user
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and a backend.conf with

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/backend/api/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

but I have a 404 not found on localhost when I do an a2inconf phpmyadmin and backend and after i reload apache2

What is wrong with my virtualhost ?

Comment: conf-availables is not enabled, softlink or create it to conf-enabled

Comment: I do a a2enconf on backend and phpmyadmin it's the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place both configs in the same VirtualHost block. You can't split it up into multiple configuration files.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/backend/api/public"
  Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
  # rest of config ...
</VirtualHost>
```